# Difference between returning calculation with function name and without

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, data-structures, computer-science

The below function calculates the Fibonacci, why the last calculation needs to include the function name and not just `(n-1)+(n-2)` ?

```js
function fibonacci(n){
    if (n===1){ return 1}
    else if (n===0){ return 0} 
    else return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2) // (n-1)+(n-2) does not work. Why?
}
```

I know this is a beginner question but couldn't find the answer. I'd appreciate any comments.
I understand that I need to use recursion, but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: This is a ***recursive*** solution.

Comment: `(n-1)+(n-2)` is the same as `n-1+n-2` is the same as `n+n-1-2` is the same as `2*n-3`. Simply an arithmetic expression whose value is calculated and returned. `fibonacci(n-1)` and `fibonacci(n-2)`, on the other hand, are function calls.

Comment: I'm having trouble understand what the point of your question is. Are you just confused by the syntax? Or do you understand what `return (n-1)+(n-2)` means, and wonder why it doesn't work? Can you explain why you thought it would work? As the question is written, it's a bit like asking "*Why is `log(n)` not the same as `n`?*" or "*Why is `x+5` not doing the same as `x`?*", and I don't know how to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is recursive solution:

```
function fibonacci(n){
    if (n===1){ return 1}
    else if (n===0){ return 0} 
    else return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2) 
}
```

You are calling this function for `nth` fibonacci. But you don't know `nth` fibonacci yet. so you must find `(n-1)` and `(n-2)` fibonacci. That is why you must call `fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)`.
And you don't even know `n-1`th and `n-2`th fibonacci that is why you must call it until known fibonacci. You know `first` and `second` fibonaccis. That is wht when n == 1 or n==0 you return just answer.

for example:

```
n = 7

fibonacci(7) = fibonacci(6) + fibonacci(5)
fibonacci(6) = fibonacci(5) + fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
fibonacci(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)
fibonacci(3) = fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)
fibonacci(2) = fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)
fibonacci(1) = 1
fibonacci(0) = 0
```